# Book: Drupal 7 Module Development (directions caused weirdness)

Tags: 7, .info

I'm reading a book, [Drupal 7 Module Development](http://www.packtpub.com/drupal-7-module-development/book), and I'm hitting some very weird outputs.

I created a folder:

```
mysite/sites/default/module/first
```

Inside this folder I created two files.

**first.info**

```
;$Id$

name = First
description = A first module
package = Drupal 7 Development
core = 7.x
files[] = first.module

;dependencies[] = autoload
;php = 5.2
```

**first.module**

```
<?php

// $Id$

/**
 * @file
 * A module exmplifying Drupal coding practices and API's.
 *
 * This module provides a block that lists all of the 
 * installed modules. It illustrates coding standards,
 * practices, and API use for Drupal 7.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 */
function first_help($path, $arg) {
    if ($path == 'admin/help#first') {
        return t('A demonstration module.');
    }
}
```

But when I activate the module, I get the contents of the first.module file spashed across the top of my page? Can someone advise me on what I am doing wrong?

This is my very first module for Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to follow the steps which I am writing below to create a module.

- Go to folder **SITES/ALL/MODULES**
- Create a folder for module, suppose *`mymodule`*
- Inside that folder create a file name *`mymodule.info`*
- Write these lines in there:

  *name = My Custom Module*

  *core = 7.x*

  *description = Custom module created for testing.*
- Create another file named *`mymodule.module`*
- Just open the PHP tag like `<?php` and save the created `.module` file
- Visit your module list & you will find this module in the list over there. If not then clear the cache for once.

Problem with your process which I saw is with the path which you followed for creating the folder for your module which **SITES/DEFAULT/MODULES**, which is not correct.

Comment: I got that path from the book. It says, **`mysite.com/modules`** is reserved for core modules, no touch... **`mysite.com/sites/all/modules`** is for Add-on modules and is not the recommended place to put custom modules unless you are running a multi-site configuration and the custom module needs to be accessible on all sites...and that **`mysite.com/sites/default/modules`** is where you put custom modules per Drupal best practices... so... now I'm confused.

Comment: Though I haven't read the book, but usually we follow the path sites/all/module path to put all the contributed & custom module. For keeping the contributed module & custom seperate from each other you can create two folder inside sites/all/modules e.g. sites/all/modules/contrib & sites/all/modules/custom. You can put modules accordingly & it will work...

Comment: After moving it I no longer get that issues with the contents of first.module displaying on screen... so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is that the exact code that is in the book?  My copy is at the office.

It looks like you have simple PHP error.  The opening line should read

```
<?php
```

and not

```
<$php
```

Make that change, and things should start working again.

Comment: it didn't. It still doesn't display a help link in the module screen, it still dumps the contents of the first.module file at the top of the screen in unformatted text... I'm so confused.

Comment: Ok... the text across the screen is actually the bad text. Almost like it isn't seeing my updated file. It's shows the $php instead of the ?php...

Comment: Go to `/admin/config/development/performance` and clear your caches.

Comment: I've cleared cache and it still pops up. I have now deleted the entire first folder and will be trying again... I'll update as needed.

Comment: Don't you think it's the path problem which he has followed to create folder for module ?

Comment: @RajeevK  Actually, no.  I have used sites/default/modules as the root for my custom modules for every single Drupal 7 site I have developed.

Comment: @MPD - It is new for me, really it was unknown for me. I will also try...thanks for info..